# Project name not appearing in debugging Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-indigo

I have cloned a Bitbucket project in my Eclipse IDE and I want to debug the project as a remote application.

However, in the debug window (->connect window), the project name is not shown.

Why do I not see it?

Answer (score 1):

I am Attaching Screenshots where you create `Debug Configurations` for any Remote Java application.

Lets Go step by step:

Within Debug Configuration Window

1. You right click `Remote Java Application > New`

In the `Connect` Tab you `browse` the project in your Workspace (One you want to debug), Here in my case it is `MyApplication` 
[image]

2. In `Sourc`e tab You Find below details where you add any dependent projects with the project that you want to debug

   When you say Add here, small dialog box comes up and here you can again choose `Java Project`, that would be one from your workspace.

[image]

I think doing this you would find your Project for Remote Debugging.
Hope this helps..!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see your problems related screenshots, but according to the situation you described, you can try the following method:

On the debugging of threads Right click it

--select Edit Source Lookup Path

--Select Add

--Select the Java Project

--choose the Java Project you worked with then click OK.

The other situation I think about is whether or not you don't have the jar that you're relying on for the project you downloaded

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. I had imported project as import project from file system. so it was not java or maven project for eclipse i guess.
i just did import as git project and tried again and it worked.